# how to add total number of votes to this program using java and the db is ms sql

Tags: java, sql, netbeans-7

```
public void ret_data(){

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; DatabaseName = mass_specc", "sa", "^mbwin1" );

        //Create Statement object
        m_Statement = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT a.cde_n18, count(a.cde_n18), c.repname_c250, d.name_c100, e.name_c250, f.regname FROM ballot as a INNER JOIN dataentry as b ON a.cde_n18 = b.cde_n18 INNER JOIN position_type as d ON a.position_n18 = d.code_n18 INNER JOIN gadi as c ON b.data_n18 = c.data_n18 INNER JOIN coop_gi as e ON c.cid_n18 = e.cid_n18 INNER JOIN regions as f ON e.region_id = f.regid GROUP BY a.cde_n18, b.data_n18, c.repname_c250, d.name_c100, e.name_c250, f.regname ORDER BY count (a.cde_n18) DESC";

        //Execute the query
        m_ResultSet = m_Statement.executeQuery(query);

        //Loop through the results
        while (m_ResultSet.next()) {
            Vector <String> d=new Vector<String>();

            d.add(m_ResultSet.getString("repname_c250"));
            d.add(m_ResultSet.getString("regname"));
            d.add(m_ResultSet.getString("name_c100"));
            d.add(m_ResultSet.getString("cde_n18"));
            data.add(d);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supply an `ALIAS` for simplicity on the aggregated field.

```
String query = "SELECT a.cde_n18, COUNT(a.cde_n18) totalCount, c.repname_c250,.."
```

and fetch the given alias,

```
d.add(m_ResultSet.getString("totalCount"));
```

Comment: where to put this " label1.setText(toString(totalVotes)); "